# Box nao flutua a esquerda(float:left nao funciona)

Tags: html, css, front-end

entao pessoal, estou começando a estudar html e css, estou tentando fazer uma pagina com um menu lateral com a homescreen ao lado, porem a box da homescreen nao sobe para o lado da barra de menu, nao sei se o codigo ta errado, se alguem puder ajudar... agradeço, segue o html e css abaixo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: ;
  font-family: roboto;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #052e40;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;

}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: #15b6ff;
}
li {
   list-style-type: none;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    src: url('roboto.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
hr {
  color: #15b6ff;
}
.home {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Nil">
  <meta name="description" content="Site Simples">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="este.css">
 </head>
 <body id="corpo">
  <!--Barra lateral/Menu-->
  <section id="Barralat">
    <div class="menu">
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Pagina Inicial</a></li>
       <hr>
       <li><a href="#">Quem Somos Nós</a></li>
       <hr>
       <li><a href="#">Cursos</a></li>
       <hr>
       <li><a href="#">Pré-Matricula</a></li>
       <hr>
       <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       <hr>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </section>
  </section>
  <!--Final da barra lateral/menu-->
  <!--pagina inicial-->
  <section class="home">
  Pagina Inicial
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o principal problema é que vc simplesmente colocou o `float` no elemento errado, vc tem colocar o `float` no primeiro elemento, assim o segundo elemento "flutua" ao lado do primeiro entende.

O problema é que ando vc coloca `float` em um elemento ele muda de escopo, e perde seus valores de referência no fluxo de conteúdo da página, então eu tive que fazer uns ajustes no seu código.

Veja abaixo como ficou, repare que o `float:left` é na barra da esquerda.

**EDIT:** Mudei um pouco o código devido ao comentário do autor da pergunta. Agora o Menu fica fixo a esquerda, e durando o scroll só as Sessões vão se mover a direita do Menu. Para fixar o Menu basta colocar o `position:fixed` assim ele não vai se mover durante o scroll. Já ppara afastar as Sessões e não deixa-las ficar por baixo do Menu basta adicionar nelas um `margin-left: 250px;`, onde 250px é equivalente a largura da coluna do Menu.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: roboto;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #052e40;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    /* vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: fixed;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #15b6ff;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    src: url('roboto.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.menu nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

hr {
    color: #15b6ff;
}

.home {
    background-color: red;
    /* width: 300px; */
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.home2 {
    background-color: green;
    /* width: 300px; */
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body id="corpo">
    <!--Barra lateral/Menu-->
    <section id="Barralat">
        <div class="menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Pagina Inicial</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#">Quem Somos Nós</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#">Cursos</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#">Pré-Matricula</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Final da barra lateral/menu-->
    <!--pagina inicial-->
    <section class="home">
        Pagina Inicial
    </section>
    <section class="home2">
        Pagina 2
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Fala irmão, sua dica funcionou, o layout ficou, em aparencia, do jeito que quero, mas ai quando fui formatar um texto na section "home", notei que que a home na verdade estava ocupando 100% ta tela por tras do menu, eu queria que ela ficasse ao lado direito do menu, pois o menu ira ficar fixo e a rolagem das sessoes sera feita ocupando apenas o restando da tela ao lado do menu. tentei colocar o width do menu em porcentagem mas desconfigura tudo.

Comment: se tu souber uma forma de resolver serei grato...

Comment: @EleniltonSilva Leia o **EDIT** que fiz na resposta e execute o código em página toda. Acho que agora ficou mais claro o que vc queria, deixei os detalhes de como fixar o menu e de como tirar a section de baixo do menu no EDIT da resposta.

Comment: ajudou muito, resolveu, obrigado.

Comment: @EleniltonSilva se resolver o problema e vc acha que a pergunta foi respondida considere marca-la como Aceita! Assim ela não fica em aberto no site como Pergunta não Resolvida. Boa sorte ai tmj